# cookie http header only contain one cookie

Tags: javascript, java, html, http, cookies

I am parsing a HttpRequest object for cookies at a Server. I used to have all cookies in one http header named 'cookie'. There are some proxies changed from Apache to Nginx. But now I see only one cookie in header. However I could retrieve cookies by calling HttpRequest.getCookies() method. But I am wondering why now there is only one cookie in header 'cookie'.  Appreciate any information on how the http header 'cookie' works, or how to control if there will be one cookie or multiple cookies could be set.

Comment: If you changed your domain/host or the proxied context path with your new reverse proxy, then some cookies might become "not-applicable" from the client side.

Comment: For now I just solved my issue to only rely on HttpRequest.getCookies() method to retrieve cookies. Probably this is the right way anyways.